# Special Character in Activity Schema Android

Tags: android, android-intent, schema, sharing

I set an intent-filter for my activity to open activity, while open the activity a URL is called . URL contain special characters like the question mark and ampersand I can't get it and android don't know my application as a host for this request. 
I use Unicode and HTML entity for that problem remained unsolved.

Comment: Can you add example how your URL looks like?

Comment: http:www.example.com/index.php?page=share&type=album&id=34

Comment: why there no slashes (`//`) after `http:`?  I think it should look like `http://www.example.com/index.php?page=share&type=album&id=34`

Could you also provide your intent-filter from manifest and how you handle opening intent with this URL?

Comment: <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/index.php?page=share&type=album" />
            </intent-filter>

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `www` in your `data` tag's `host` attribute. It should look like this:

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

    <data
        android:host="www.example.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/index.php"
        android:scheme="http"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Also don't include params in `pathPrefix`, you can extract them in Activity code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    if(data != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + data.toString());
        Set<String> names = data.getQueryParameterNames();
        for(String name : names) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: param " + name + ": " + data.getQueryParameter(name));
        }
    }
```

Test it with adb (note escaped `&`):

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://www.example.com/index.php?page=share\&type=album\&id=34" com.example.myapplication
```

Output is:

```
12-03 13:10:41.924 32595-32595/com.example.myapplication D/MainActivity: onCreate: http://www.example.com/index.php?page=share&type=album&id=34
12-03 13:10:41.924 32595-32595/com.example.myapplication D/MainActivity: onCreate: param page: share
12-03 13:10:41.924 32595-32595/com.example.myapplication D/MainActivity: onCreate: param type: album
12-03 13:10:41.924 32595-32595/com.example.myapplication D/MainActivity: onCreate: param id: 34
```

Comment: i need to manage links that have params so i can't ignore that, finally i solve the problem with airbnb/DeepLinkDispatch library, but still i have my question unanswered. thank you